# Drupal 7 - CKEditor does not display images

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

`CKEditor` does not display images when editing "Full HTML". So, for instance, if a page has existing images and I edit it, the images do not display in the editor. This also happens if I try to add an image via the `Add media` button. This happens for all roles, including the main admin. If I click on `Switch to plain text editor` the HTML for the image is present and correct.

All modules and Drupal 7 are latest versions, and up to date.

I've spent a lot of time trying to work out what is going on, to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

The text format needs to allow  tags, otherwise they will be stripped out by default.

For example, add  to the allowed tags here:

admin/config/content/formats/full_html > "Limit allowed HTML tags"

Comment: "Limit allowed HTML tags" is not enabled so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: JavaScript and other extra content tags are removed in latest CKeditor 4.1. So either you should enable the "Limit allowed HTML tags" from admin settings for required tags or you could try this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/ckeditor-acf-configuration-1950498-25.patch) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not say if you're using the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, or if you're using the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module (in which you then configure the CKEditor 'library').

I always use the WYSIWYG module (to leave the options open for a customer to pick another editor if they'd want, e.g. TinyMCE). If however I select the CKEditor library (using WYSIWYG module), then I've noticed that I must use the (older) 3.6.x version of the CKEditor, since WYSIWYG module seems to not yet support the 4.x version of CKEditor. That is: if I first try the 4.x version of CKEditor, then the WYSIWYG module doesn't find/enable it.

As per the comment from Anurag about CKEditor 4.1, it appears to me that it might be worth trying the WYSIWYG module approach, together with CKEditor 3.6.x library. Another option might be, if you use CKEditor "module", to try to use the 3.6.x version of the "library" (I don't have experience with that combination though).

Curious to hear if this helps. Or maybe how you resolved it already in some other way (but didn't tell on SO yet ...)?